# Why do my keyboard presses result in wrong letters?

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-layout

I have an ASUS Q301 running Windows 8.

When I press some of the keys, they do not function properly. For example, when I press the letter `P`, a `*` will be printed. Same goes for others like `0`, `;`, and `/` .

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you spill water on the keyboard at some point?

Comment: Please reopen this question in case it gets closed. The symptom described by the user refers to a *very specific* situation involving having NumLock on with a "compact" keyboard. There is only one possible answer here. The "P" -> `*` gave it away to me.

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple fix: simply press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>NumLck</kbd>.

This will turn **NumLock** off.

If you look more closely at your keys, you will probably see that it looks something like this:

[image: keyboard layout]

See the `*` under the `P`? This is saying, "If you have NumLock on, then this is the key you will get." This provides support for a "native" NumPad (the NumPad `*`, `1-9`, etc. keys are considered different keys by the operating system). Unfortunately, from the images I could find of your system, it appears that the alternate key presses are not printed on the key labels. This is likely a cost saving measure enacted by ASUS, or they didn't want to confuse the user. But NumLock does indeed appear to treat about half of your keyboard as a numpad.